# Disk block size and hadoop block size

Tags: hadoop

I have read many posts saying Hadoop block size of 64 MB reduces metadata and helps in performance improvement over 4 kb block size. But, why data block size is exactly 4kb in OS Disk and 64 MB in Hadoop.

Why not 100 or some other bigger number?

Comment: You are confusing HDFS and an actual OS filesystem... HDFS is just an abstraction. Larger files, means less management (namenode memory usage), and the current default is actually 128MB. Regarding "why not 100", well, the binary system doesn't really like sizes that aren't powers of two, but feel free to edit the HDFS block size to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

> But, why data block size is exactly 4kb in OS Disk and 64 MB in Hadoop.

In HDFS we store huge amounts of data as compared to a single OS filesystem. So, it doesn't make sense to have small block sizes for HDFS. By having small block sizes, there will be more blocks and the NameNode has to store more metadata about the blocks. And also fetching of the data will be slow as data from higher number of blocks dispersed across many machines has to fetched.

> Why not 100 or some other bigger number?

Initially the HDFS block size was 64MB and now it's 128MB by default. Check the dfs.blocksize property in hdfs-site.xml [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml). This is because of the bigger and better storage capacities and speed (HDD and SSD). We shouldn't be surprised when later it's changed to 256MB.

Check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zw6KHOtbT4MmRkZWJjYzEtYjI3Ni00NTFjLWE0OGItYTU5OGMxYjc0N2M1/view) HDFS comic to get a quick overview about HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, the following is also relevant:

Blocks on an OS level and blocks on a HDFS level are different concepts. When you have a 10kb file on the OS, then that essentially means 3 blocks of 4kb get allocated, and the result is that you consume 12kb. 
Obviously you don't want to allocate a large fraction of your space to blocks that are not full, so you need a small blocksize.

On HDFS however, the content of the block determines the size of the block.
So if you have 129MB that could be stored in 1 block of 128MB and 1 block of 1MB. (I'm not sure if it will spread it out differently).

As a result you don't 'lose' the 127 mb which is not allocated.

With this in mind you will want to have a comparatively large blocksize to optimize block management.